# Huge org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader memory usage

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

Over time my unused running my Spring Boot v1.3.2 application gradually increases memory consumption until it eventually falls over. By unused I mean no client requested are being served apart from the regular ping of the `/health` end point.

[image]

According to the Eclipse Memory Analyser, `org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader` is taking up a massive 920MB.

[image]

It appears as though Spring Boot is continually loading classes

[image]

Any ideas what's going on?

**EDIT**

Looks like it's Spring Cloud Consul that's causing the issue:

[image]

Comment: That's certainly not typical behaviour for a Spring Boot app. Unfortunately, it's impossible to figure out why it's happening from the information you've provided. The output from running with `-verbose:class` will identify what's being loaded and that might help to figure out why.

Comment: What versions of Spring Cloud bits are you using? Can you post a sample app please?

Answer (score 2):

Appears to be a memory leak in Spring Cloud Consul. Raised issue https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/183